# Description for android application on google play in language diffrent from English

Tags: android, google-play

I like to upload apk file on google play store and I like to add short description and description in language different from predefined languages. Is it possible and how can I achive this?

EDIT: I have only this in manage translations:

[image]

Comment: Post-edit 1: Click on the menu item that says `Add your own translation text`. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: No it is not because it lists me only predifened languages, I can't add my own

Comment: I want to add Mongolian but Mongolian isn't on the list. Did you ever solve your problem? There are apps on Google play that have Mongolian descriptions so there must be a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible.

1. Log into the Google play Developer Console.
2. From the Store Listing tab, where you add your title and short
   description, there is a drop down for 'Manage Translations'.
3. Hit that dropdown and choose 'Add your own translation Text'.
4. Choose a new locale and it will show up as a new button
5. Select that new locale button and add your description.

Answer (score 1):

Many languages are not available yet under Manage Translations > Add Your Own Translation Text. What you can do is just choose a default language (like English) and add Macedonian (or in my case, Mongolian). For me, I put both English and Mongolian on the same page, one below the other. But you could just put Macedonian. However, when you try to submit an update, the following warning appears:

> We might be wrong, but we found some things that don't look quite
>   right. You might want to check the fields for the highlighted
>   languages.

And the "Submit update" button greys out. I contacted Google and they said:

> Thanks for contacting Google Play Developer Support. Although we don't
>   currently support Mongolian as a localization option, you should be
>   able to add your text in any other language. Keep in mind that the
>   warning message you're seeing is only a warning and it should not
>   prevent you from publishing your app.

They didn't mention what to do about the greyed out "Submit update" button, but I discovered if I just made a minor change (like adding a space and then deleting it) then I could click the "Submit update" button again. And submitting it the second time worked.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by 'predefined languages'?
On the play store you may put your own translations in any language, the play store itself is able to display (currently about 50).
Just go to your store entry -> manage translations -> add custom translation

Comment: I mean on language that is not in that list of 50 languages

Comment: I'm afraid, that is not possible. Which language are you thinking of (just for interest)?

Comment: I am thinking of Macedonian

Answer (score 0):

***I am thinking of Macedonian***

It doesn't seem to be on the list - interesting. In which language is the macedonian play store displayed (I guess English). I will upvote your question, but maybe you want to edit it to be more specific.

You probably have to get into contact with the Google Play Store team to get more Infos:

https://support.google.com/googleplay/
-> See Contact Button on the top right.

Comment: Google Play support just suggests a bunch of things that apply to this question and it doesn't give a chance to send a message to a real person.

Comment: Click on 'call me'. They usually call you back within seconds after submitting your number.

Answer (score 0):

Even that there was a warning that my language is not supported by google play, when my application was published the text was correct, I mean that warning does not metter to application publishing.